# javascript css3 change background color every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, css, html, transition, background-color

How can I change the HTML background color automatically every 2 seconds? HTML5 with CSS3 fade in or fadeout?

I tried to use transition with timer and CSS target without any success

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}

label {
     display: block;
     background: #08C;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
     border-radius: 2px;
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .to-be-changed {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A few changes** A variation on this should work in modern browsers, if you know the colors and the number of colors in advance:

```css
.animate-me {
  -webkit-animation: bgcolorchange 4s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: 4s infinite bgcolorchange;
}
@keyframes bgcolorchange {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 @-webkit-keyframes bgcolorchange {
      0%   {background: red;}
      25%  {background: yellow;}
      75%  {background: green;}
      100% {background: blue;}
 }
```

```html
<div class="animate-me">Trippy! Give me a headache!</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnw7xza2/1/

Click to demo[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nnw7xza2/1/)!

Answer (score 0):

**Figure it up with:
-css3 
-html5
-javascript timer**

```js
var arrColor = ["#45c1bf", "#f0593e", "#aeacd4", "#bdd630", "#4479bd", "#f5b11e"];
var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
//helper function - get dark or lighter color
function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {
    var usePound = false;
    if (col[0] == "#") {
      col = col.slice(1);
      usePound = true;
    }
    var num = parseInt(col, 16);
    var r = (num >> 16) + amt;
    if (r > 255) r = 255;
    else if (r < 0) r = 0;
    var b = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;
    if (b > 255) b = 255;
    else if (b < 0) b = 0;
    var g = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
    if (g > 255) g = 255;
    else if (g < 0) g = 0;
    return (usePound ? "#" : "") + (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);
  }
  //random new color

function GetNewColor() {
    var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    return arrColor[index];
  }
  // set new color

function SetNewColor(color) {
    document.body.style.background = color;
    var NewColor = LightenDarkenColor(color, -20);
    footer.style.backgroundColor = NewColor;
    header.style.backgroundColor = NewColor;
    //footer.style.opacity = 1.2;
  }
  // on document load function start
  (function() {
    var colorSelected = GetNewColor();
    SetNewColor(colorSelected);
  })();
//change color timer
window.setInterval(function() {
  var colorSelected = GetNewColor();
  SetNewColor(colorSelected);
}, 2000);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #bdd630;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
}
#header {
  background: #000;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  /* Now, to activate scrollbars
           and compensate #footer height: */
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#footer {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  /* cause of fixed pos */
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>content here</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Enjoy

Comment: I don't understand, why post a question seeking help when you had the answer all along?

Comment: @Danko Thank you for pointing out the obvious, I just think more researching was needed before posting.

Comment: @Danko,  If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question"  See his rep....

Comment: @Chilion recently has increased with the upvotes here :P ... I just  link that since the site allows that kind of selfanswered but alsot think must be a big issue or problem not every code you develop

Comment: @hod caspi change your "reputation" every 2 seeconds instead? didnt got your logic answering your own question after one minute? seems you alredy knew the answer

Comment: @Danko thanks just start sharing new things here, thank you all

Comment: @AbdulBasit Share it with others

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an easy to understand way to do this, check out [Basecacti](https://basecacti.bitballoon.com). Of course, Basecacti as of now does not include embedding of the background on to your own html page, so just look at the source code behind it. Here's an example if you need it:

```
var clr1 = renderColors("clr1");
    var clr2 = renderColors("clr2");
    var clr3 = renderColors("clr3");
    var speed = renderColors("speed");

    var deb = document.body;
    var circle = 0;
    deb.style.backgroundColor = clr1;

    setInterval(function(){
        if (circle == 0) {
            deb.style.backgroundColor = clr2;
            circle = 1;
        }
        else if (circle == 1) {
            deb.style.backgroundColor = clr3;
            circle = 2;
        }
        else {
            deb.style.backgroundColor = clr1;
            circle = 0;
        }
    }, speed);
```

To make this work for you, define 3 different colors as `clr1`, `clr2`, and `clr3`. Then set the speed variable to `2000` for 2 secs, and it should work. (The renderColors function that defines these values in the above code is what Basecacti uses to get the colors that users define from a different webpage.) Also, Basecacti is Open-Source for now, so you might want to hurry over to their site and get this code ASAP. If you only want the background to change once after 2 seconds, change the function from `setInterval` to `setTimeout`, but don't change anything else. Please comment on this post if the Basecacti website shuts down or stops working, or if I have an error in the code.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://basecacti.bitballoon.com/cacti/image.html?clr1=royalblue&clr2=coral&clr3=greenyellow&speed=1000) of a Basecacti-generated background.